# Returning a struct from function

Tags: c, struct, codeblocks

I'm trying to understand how to return a struct from a function but I'm completely lost.

Here is the code:

```
void initialize_server(struct data host_port){

        printf(" Set IP Address (X.X.X.X): ");
        fgets(data.host, sizeof(data.host), stdin);
        strchomp(data.host);

        printf(" Set Port: ");
        fgets(data.port_inc, sizeof(data.port_inc), stdin);
        strchomp(data.port_inc);

        return data;
}
```

and heres the code from the .h

```
struct data{
    char host[16];
    char port_inc[8];
};

void initialize_server(struct data host_port);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The function definition

Your function definition uses `void`, which defines the function as returning *nothing*, therefore your `return` statement is useless (will discuss this later).

## Use of structures

Also the definition seems a little broken. You have written:

```
void initialize_server(struct data host_port) {
```

Then in your function you write things like `data.host`. I'm assuming that you have a `struct` definition for `data` somewhere and `host_port` is the variable of type `struct data`.

To create a variable of type `struct some-struct-name` you would write `struct some-struct-name your-variable-name`. So in your code you could have

```
struct data {
    char host[SIZE];
    port_inc[SIZE];
}
```

This *defines* the layout of your new composite data type. The *type* is identified by the name `data`. To create variables of this *type* you would declare them as follows:

```
struct data my_new_data_struct;  // A data structure on the stage of type
struct data *my_new_data_struct; // A pointer to data structure that 
                                 // would normally be allocated on the heap
```

## Possible solutions

### Use structures passed by value

You could write your function as follows to return the structure, but it will be a little inefficient, because by returning a structure you are likely to be having to utilise the [***stack***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) to return the data and you are also using the [***stack***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) to pass in the parameter to the function. This is called [***pass-by-value***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).

struct data initialize_server(struct data host_port)

Then replace all `data.` bits with `host_port.`:

```
void initialize_server(struct data host_port)
{
        printf(" Set IP Address (X.X.X.X): ");
        fgets(**host_port**.host, sizeof(**host_port**.host), stdin);
        strchomp(**host_port**.host);

        printf(" Set Port: ");
        fgets(**host_port**.port_inc, sizeof(**host_port**.port_inc), stdin);
        strchomp(**host_port**.port_inc);

        return **host_port**;
}
```

### Use pointers

What might be better is to pass in a pointer to the data structure as follows:

```
void initialize_server(struct data *const host_port)
```

This defines the function `initialize_server` as returning nothing, so you won't need to return anyway because not `host_port` is a pointer. The function would then become:

```
void initialize_server(struct data *const host_port)
{
        printf(" Set IP Address (X.X.X.X): ");
        fgets(data.host, sizeof(host_port->host), stdin);
        strchomp(host_port->host);

        printf(" Set Port: ");
        fgets(host_port->port_inc, sizeof(host_port->port_inc), stdin);
        strchomp(host_port->port_inc);
}
```

But now note that when you call this function you must pass in a pointer! So you might have something like:

```
void do_something( )
{
   struct data my_host_port;
   //do stuff
   initialize_server( &my_host_port); // NOTE: The ampersand!!
   // do stuff
}
```

Or you might `malloc()` your host port as follows.

```
void do_something( )
{
   struct data *my_host_port = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
   //do stuff
   initialize_server(my_host_port); // NOTE: NO ampersand as my_host_port  now already a pointer!!
   // do stuff
   free(my_host_port); // NOTE: You must free() what you malloc()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Some problems in the code**:

- The return type of your function is `void`, which means: return nothing. This has to be `struct data`.
- Inside your function `host_port.host` has to be used instead of `data.host`.
- You'll need to return `host_port`, not `data` (`struct data` is the type, `host_port` is the name of the parameter).

**Solution**:

First, it's easier to use a [typedef](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) for `struct data`:

```
typedef struct data {
    char host[16];
    char port_inc[8];
} data;
```

Now, `data` can be used as the type instead of `struct data`.

```
data initialize_server(data host_port){

    printf(" Set IP Address (X.X.X.X): ");
    fgets(host_port.host, sizeof(host_port.host), stdin);
    strchomp(host_port.host);

    printf(" Set Port: ");
    fgets(host_port.port_inc, sizeof(host_port.port_inc), stdin);
    strchomp(host_port.port_inc);

    return host_port;
}
```

Or even use a [pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) to `struct data` as parameter, to avoid copying the whole struct:

```
void initialize_server(data *host_port){

    printf(" Set IP Address (X.X.X.X): ");
    fgets(host_port->host, sizeof(host_port->host), stdin);
    strchomp(host_port->host);

    printf(" Set Port: ");
    fgets(host_port->port_inc, sizeof(host_port->port_inc), stdin);
    strchomp(host_port->port_inc);
}
```

This can be called as follows:

```
data dt;
initialize_server(&dt); // takes the address of dt
```

On return, `dt` will contain the modified values.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, data is name of struct, just like int is a name of type. And host_port is a name of a variable. So use host_port instead of data where possible
Secondly, the return type is void and not struct data. Change it too.

```
struct data initialize_server(struct data host_port){

        printf(" Set IP Address (X.X.X.X): ");
        fgets(host_port.host, sizeof(host_port.host), stdin);
        strchomp(host_port.host);

        printf(" Set Port: ");
        fgets(host_port.port_inc, sizeof(data.port_inc), stdin);
        strchomp(host_port.port_inc);

        return host_port;
}
```

Also consider writing

```
struct data_struct {
    char host[16];
    char port_inc[8];
} data;
```

As far as you set all fields of structure in your function, you can remove a parameter from function:

```
struct data initialize_server(){
        struct data host_port;
        printf(" Set IP Address (X.X.X.X): ");
        fgets(host_port.host, sizeof(host_port.host), stdin);
        strchomp(host_port.host);
//...
```

Or pass it by pointer and modify inside your function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a struct :

```
struct a_tag {
   char c;
   int i;
   char *w;
};
```

You can declare a function that returns a struct like this :

```
struct a_tag  return_struct(void);
```

Then, you can write something like this :

```
int main() {
   struct a_tag a1;
   a1 = return_struct();
   return 0;
}
```

And you have define your function like this :

```
/* return_struct: return a struct by value (copied) */
struct a_tag return_struct(void) {
   struct a_tag a;
   a.c = 'Y';
   a.i = 88;
   a.w = "My dog has fleas";
   /* can return local auto storage, because it is copied */
   return a;
}
```

That's the basic concept around functions returning struct. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of All,in order to return a variable from a function,the return type of the function has to be similar to the type of the variable.so a function of type `void` can't return anything.Since you want to return a `struct`,change the prototype of your function to:`struct data initialize_server(struct data host_port);`
Next,you can't return a type,but the object created by that type.

So write `return host_port;`